# How to calculate the Automatic differentiation of an arbitrary function in python

Tags: python, class, numerical-methods, mpmath, numerical-computing

I'm using the mpmath library to compute a self defined function `f(x)` and needed to compute its higher order derivatives.

I found the Automatic differentiation on Wikipedia and found it useful.

```
# Automatic Differentiation
import math

class Var:
    def __init__(self, value, children=None):
        self.value = value
        self.children = children or []
        self.grad = 0
        print(children)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Var(self.value + other.value, [(1, self), (1, other)])

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Var(self.value * other.value, [(other.value, self), (self.value, other)])

    def sin(self):
        return Var(math.sin(self.value), [(math.cos(self.value), self)])

    def calc_grad(self, grad=1):
        self.grad += grad
        for coef, child in self.children:
            child.calc_grad(grad * coef)

# Example: f(x, y) = x * y + sin(x)
x = Var(2)
y = Var(3)
f = x * y + x.sin()

# Calculation of partial derivatives
f.calc_grad()

print("f =", f.value)
print("∂f/∂x =", x.grad)
print("∂f/∂y =", y.grad)
```

which returned

```
None
None
[(3, <__main__.Var object at 0x000001EDDCCA2260>), (2, <__main__.Var object at 0x000001EDDCCA1300>)]
[(-0.4161468365471424, <__main__.Var object at 0x000001EDDCCA2260>)]
[(1, <__main__.Var object at 0x000001EDDCCA0A30>), (1, <__main__.Var object at 0x000001EDDCCA0BB0>)]
f = 6.909297426825682
∂f/∂x = 2.5838531634528574
∂f/∂y = 2
```

However, I have some question about how the code was implemented. For example, I guessed that the children list was the derivatives with Chain rule, but I'm not sure how the statement such as `[(1, self), (1, other)]` implemented this recursion.

Also, the Automatic Differentiation in this code seemed to be written as more of a "symbolic calculation" in disguise, and I'm not sure if it will work for arbitrary function and at arbitrary order. For example, I wanted to try the second order derivatives but `f.calc_grad(grad=2).value` and `f.calc_grad().calc_grad( ).value`didn't work, I suppose it was because the `cos` function was not defined.

How to calculate the Automatic differentiation of an arbitrary function in python? Can I not define a class function but to work with mpmath directly?

Comment: Why not use sympy and the differentiation provided there?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Sympy was known to be slow and it restricted the data type. By customize the automatic differentiation for the specific operations, efficient computation of arbitrary order of derivative to arbitrary precession might be achieved and to by passes the rounding errors. Also, I wanted to try an example of the Automatic differentiation myself as part of the study.

Comment: There was an attempt to make the symbolic kernel faster, `symengine`. I did not test that and how it integrates, it is the basis for `jitcode`. // What you get is the encoding of the Jacobian as a graph, so that you can compute directional derivatives and gradients. // Second derivatives are implemented as combination of forward and backward pass, which will of course also need second order information in the nodes, which is not present in this code example. // Arbitrarily high order mixed derivatives is a balance of space and accuracy (also time) and not an easy topic.